# Find the radius of convergence for $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n^2+a^n)z^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

Find the radius of convergence for $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n^2+a^n)z^n$, where $a$ is a complex number.

I'm not sure what the best way to solve this is, I know that $\sum(n^2+a^n)z^n=\sum a^nz^n+\sum n^2z^n$

Which both the sums on the right have radius of convergence $R=1$.

And I know there is a formula $1/R=\lim\sup\vert n^2+a^n\vert^{1/n}$ but I'm not sure how to compute that.

Comment: You cannot distribute the sums unless they both converge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not right: for $a \ne 0$ the power series  $\sum a^nz^n$ has radius of convergence $\frac{1}{|a|}.$
Now discuss two cases:

(1)  $|a| \le 1$ and (2) $|a| >1.$

Comment: It diverges for $\vert a\vert>1$ and converges for $\vert a\vert \leq 1$?